# repositioning cursor in a textbox which has label text in it tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried searching for a answer, but nothing I look at is what I need to code the python tkinter textbox to do, I am using a database and the info is data protected
Problem:

```
profile_window = toplevel()
my_textbox = Text(profile_window, font=16)
my_textbox.place(x=830, `y=20,height=525,width=450)`
first_line_label = Label(my_textbox, text='stuff')
second_line_label=Label(my_textbox,text=record[3])
third_line_label=Label(my_textbox, text='stuff')
```

the cursor always starts at 1.0 beside first_line_label i need the cursor to start further down textbox 1.110+count all labels has info from database, i have tried

```
my_textbox.focus() 
my_textbox.lift()
my_textbox.see("insert")
my_textbox.mark_set("insert", index='1.110')
```

this all dont move the cursor to index 1.110

any ideas or help would be grateful
thanks

Comment: You can't move to position 1.110 unless there are actually 110 characters on line 1.  If you do have that many items in the text widget, `mark_set("insert", "1.110")` is the way to move the insertion point to that character position. The code you provided isn't enough to reproduce your problem. Please try to include a runnable [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(count):
    my_textbox.insert(END, '\n')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: For example, you could explain the variable `count`.